# Neo4j CALL subquery with UNWIND returns 0 records

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have came across a strange behaviour when using `UNWIND` in `CALL` sub queries. The following query returns no records:

```
WITH [] as a, [1] as b, [1,2] as c
CALL {
    WITH a
    UNWIND a as row
    RETURN row as A
}
CALL {
    WITH b
    UNWIND b as row
    RETURN row as B
}
CALL {
    WITH c
    UNWIND c as row
    RETURN row as C
}
RETURN A, B, C
```

Result:

```
(no changes, no records)
```

I assume it's because of `UNWIND`-ing an empty list, [reduces](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/#unwind-using-unwind-with-an-empty-list) the number of rows to zero.

However, when I change the `RETURN` clause on the first sub query to `collect(row)`, the query suddenly returns two records (because of list `c` with 2 entries):

```
WITH [] as a, [1] as b, [1,2] as c
CALL {
    WITH a
    UNWIND a as row
    RETURN collect(row) as A
}
CALL {
    WITH b
    UNWIND b as row
    RETURN row as B
}
CALL {
    WITH c
    UNWIND c as row
    RETURN row as C
}
RETURN A, B, C
```

Result:

```
╒═══╤═══╤═══╕
│A  │B  │C  │
╞═══╪═══╪═══╡
│[] │1  │1  │
├───┼───┼───┤
│[] │1  │2  │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Why does `collect()` in the subquery alter the result of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagnosis of the first result is correct. The second is a result of the behaviour of aggregating functions: `collect()` returns one row even when there are no incoming rows.

See [this article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-aggregations-on-zero-rows/) for more information.

Comment: I didn't know about the special behavior of `collect()`, especially in combination with a grouping key. That helped a lot!